# passing data between class based forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am fairly new to Django and class based forms, and I am having trouble understanding how these interact with each other. Following from the [django project example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms), I have tried to build a "search form", which would sit on all pages of my project:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    myquery = forms.CharField(max_length=255,label="", help_text="sq")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.myquery

# views.py
from searchapp.forms import SearchForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class SearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = SearchForm
    success_url = '/searchres/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thequery=form.cleaned_data.get('myquery')
        return super(SearchView, self).form_valid(form)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SearchResView(SearchView):
    template_name = 'searchres.html'


#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from deals.views import IndexView
from searchapp.views import SearchView, SearchResView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/', SearchView.as_view(),name="home"),
    url(r'^searchres/', SearchResView.as_view(),name="searchresx"),
)
```

The plan is the start off with a simple form for user to enter the search query, and also show the input form on the results page. I have the following questions here (sorry - I am a Django newbie esp. to Class Based Views):

- How does one pass data ("thequery") to the success_url? i.e I would like success_url to have access to "thequery" so that I can use something like {{thequery}} on my template tags.
- Upon submitting the form(name="home"), I see POST data from the form on my firebug, but I am able to see just "myquery" rather than "thequery". How does one use get_context_data() here to add/post "thequery" variable aswell?
- Finally, I was wondering if it would be possible to construct the success_url based on "thequery" string i.e something like success_url = '/searchres/?q=' + thequery

Thank you in advance - I am hoping to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using function based views for this. If you choose to subclass a generic view you will need to dig through a lot of documentation and possibly source code, to find the right methods to override. (If you're really keen then look at the `ListView` class along with the `get_queryset()`, `get()` and `post()` methods)

A single django view will normally handle both rendering the empty form AND processing the submitted form.

So the search page (both the form and the results), live at http://your-site.com/search. Your url conf is -

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #...
    (r'^search/$', 'searchapp.views.search'),
)
```

And your view looks something like this -

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_query = form.cleaned_data['myquery']
            object_list = YourModel.objects.filter(# some operation involving my_query)
            return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'object_list': object_list})
     else:
        form = SearchForm()
     render_to_response('search_form.html', {'form': form})
```

(Note I've assumed your form method is post rather than get - I know this isn't great http but it's a common pattern with django)

To respond to your questions -

1. Don't use your own method for cleaning data. Add a [clean_myquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method to your form and access it with `form.fields['myquery'].clean()` (or if you've called `is_valid()` on your form, it's accessible with just `form.cleaned_data['myquery']`).

You want to try and avoid passing data for processing to the template. Do as much processing as you can in the view, then render the template. However if you want to pass myquery as a string for the template to render, then add it in to the context dictionary (the second non-key-word argument) in `render_to_response` -

```
return render_to_response('search.html', {'object_list': object_list, 'myquery': my query})
```

1. The post data is constructed from the form fields. You don't have a form field `thequery`. The view is processing the POST data - it's not creating it that's done by the html (which in turn is constructed by the Form class). Your variable `thequery` is declared in the view.
2. Django's URL dispatcher ignores query strings in the URL so http://your_site.com/ssearch will be processed by the same view as http://your_site.com/search?myquery=findstuff. Simply change the html in the template from `<form method='post'>` to  and access the data in django with `request.GET`. (You'll need to change the code from the view I described above to include a new check to see whether you're dealing with a form submission or just rendering a blank form)

Have a good read of the docs on [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/), [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) and the [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for your detailed response. I have used form processed in FBV and it is pretty much the code you have on top. My problem is that I want to replicate this in CBV - and particularly, I am not sure which function to override to pass/add object_list to search_form.html To be honest, I am quite new to Django, and I am not sure I would be able to figure this out from the source code - but this is excatly what Iam going to try now. ps: I have changed code for cleaned_data - please let me know if this looks ok. Thanks!

Comment: cleaned_data won't be in the format you want unless you add the clean_myquery method to the form class. To make your object_list variable accessible to your template, you need to override get_context_data() in your class based model. If you found my answer helpful, perhaps you might consider voting it up.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have now added a clean_myquery method and then access the data using form.cleaned_data['myquery'] under form.valid(). I will try to overide get_context_data and see what happens. I have already upvoted your answer - going to accept it now. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks John, glad you're making progress.